# Running both NodeJS and Python code on a Lambda function

Tags: python, node.js, aws-lambda, runtime

I have some python libraries that I need to invoke in NodeJS on a Lambda function. I need to do this because some of the python functions are doing external API calls and may take a while to finish, and using NodeJS speeds this up quite a lot thanks to promises.

I have read it is possible to crate custom runtimes as Layers but canont find some samples on NodeJS 12 + Python 3.7 for example, so how to do that? is there a list of already published and available runtimes somewhere?

Comment: something like this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel no, a runtime on AWS Lambda where you have both NodeJS and Python........

Comment: can you create individual lambdas for your node runtimes, then invoke those lambda functions (synchronously) from your python lambda?

Comment: @LostJon hum the idea is more the opposite, the code is in Python but I need to orchestrate with NodeJS. So yeah I could do that but it would mean adding the time to start the lambda function for each python process on the overall time, I think doing it all in one lambda might me more time efficient? I will do some tests to see the time difference from other options

Answer (score 1):

I think the newly announced option to run Docker images in AWS Lambda might be the best solution here.

You can use either the Python or the NodeJS base image provided by Amazon and then install the rest of the required dependencies. Put it into AWS ECR and then run your Lambda using the Docker image.

Check the [news article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/).

Comment: yes I was actually trying that as well, but when I built my custom container and did some tests, I was having a `Init Duration: 6544.74 ms` instead of `Init Duration: 1066.99 ms` when using the default `python3.7` environment. I am following the example in https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-nodejs-runtime-interface-client but based on the image `nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.7-nodejs12` (which might not be the lightest one?). I am not an ace in Docker so currently not the best solution as this init duration is not saving me much compute time...

Comment: @Guillaume are those init durations cold-start times? Is the second request faster? If so, then you might want to have a look at provisioned concurrency, which basically eliminates cold starts.